# Error when showing QMessageBox in setModelData

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to alert the user when typing invalid data by showing a QMessageBox. The problem is that its giving me this error: TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call. The code I wrote is this:

```
def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
    if index.column() == 1:
        data = editor.text()
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_("select * from gaceta where nombre='%s'" % (data,))
        if query.next():
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', 'Ya hay una Gaceta con ese nombre')
        else:
            model.setData(index, QVariant(data))
```

I look for an element with the same name in the database and if I find any I don't set the data and instead inform the user of the validation error. If there is a better way of doing this please tell, thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling this from within a subclass of `QItemDelegate`. `QItemDelegate` subclasses `QAbstractItemDelegate` which in turn subclasses `QObject`.

The first argument of `QMessageBox.warning` must be a derivative of `QWidget` which as you can see from my above explanation, `QItemDelegate` is not. As such, you are getting an error that the arguments you passed to `QMessageBox.warning` were of the wrong type.

So instead of passing `self` you need an actual `QWidget`. You could try using the `editor` variable as it contains a QWidget derivative (your textbox). I can't see why that wouldn't work. However, if you do run into trouble with that solution, you might need to instead pass a reference for another widget into your `QItemDelegate` constructor which you can store and reference later.

Comment: I changed self for the editor and everything worked as expected. Did know that the first argument of `QMessageBox` had to be a `QWidget`. Thnks